# How to handle Caching for huge pages using Smarty 3

Tags: php, mysql, caching, filesystems, smarty3

I am currently running a project that has millions of dynamic pages. Contents for those pages is gathered from the Database, and of course the database is large too with many Tables. Since those database contents will not change frequently and to reduce the unnecessary burden to the server for MySQL connections and queries I have implemented Smarty caching with a duration of seven days or a month depending on the content type.

Now, my problem is that I have huge numbers of cached pages on my single cache directory and I somehow begin to think it may have decreased the overall performances.

So, can anyone tell me the performance issues on having millions of cached pages on a single directory? Or, how do I manage storing those cached files? Or, how do I correctly utilize Smarty Caching for huge number of pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that placing all cache files inside single directory does not create any performances issues unless we are going to read files in a loop.

However, there is an issue with the latest version of smarty (3.1.13 at the time of writing this answer) (see discussion on [smarty forum](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21143)). When clearing cache for specific cache id or group, smarty reads all the files one by one which takes some time for a single cache to get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

serve your dynamic pages HTML content directly to user.
You can do this in different ways.
There are too many ways to do it but you have the millions of pages then apply this procedure.

1. When any user comes first check is cache is exists for that page
2. If not then cache generate and serve the page
3. and basic on cache file expiry you can re-generate that cache file again.

The based library i can suggest you is that PEAR cacheLiet or this is very simple you can write your own code. But benefits of using PEAR cacheLite is that it have many drivers like file, database and other caching system.

For caching directory you different files based on your site categories or tags which you site  is having.

Comment: I have implemented all the suggested list with Smarty Caching. I want to know about any performances issues while having millions of cached pages in a single directory or if there are any better solution while staying with Smarty 3.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Varnish as a reverse-proxy cache. It is perfect for caching lots and lots of static pages.